# Using Spree, how can I find product option values from an order in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, spree

I am able to get products from an order, but I still didn't find a way to get its option_values in order to produce it. This is how I found the product:

```
  p = Order.find_by_number("R326153622").products.first
```

Then, I have its option_types through `p.option_types` which gives me:

```
=> [#<OptionType id: 935339118, name: "gender", ...>, 
    #<OptionType id: 935339117, name: "size", ...>, 
    #<OptionType id: 643188970, name: "color", ...>]
```

Ok! Now my headache starts. I just can't realize where to find the gender, size, and color of this product, chosen by the customer when he put it in his cart.

I'm giving up and calling the customer right away, but still wanted to understand it =D

Answer (score -1):

you can do it like so

```
  p = Order.find_by_number("R326153622").products.first
```

then

```
  p.option_types.map(&:name)
```

what is happening here is that this form

```
 array.map(&:method_name)
```

call this methods on each one of array members

Comment: I believe this answer works to get the option_types but OP was asking about option_values. I am having the same problem. I used `p.option_types.first.option_values`
but it returns or possible option values, not just those associated with `p`

Comment: OP wants the option values **user has selected**; `Order.Product` refers to the original listing and hence `Order.Product.OptionTypes` and `Order.Product.OptionTypes.OptionValues` would obviously return all possible `OptionTypes` and `OptionValues` something like `{ "size" : [ "s", "m", "l"], "gender": ["m", "f"]}` each element in array being an object with `id` , `name` and `price`