# What is the right way to add product options user has selected to cart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-schema, shopping-cart

Here's how my schema looks like:

```
Combo      |    Product     |    Variant        |   OptionType    |   OptionValue
  id       |      id        |      id, name     |     id          |     id
  name     |      name      |      price        |     name        |     name
  dicount  |      combo_id  |      product_id   |     variant_id  |     option_type_id
                            |      price        |                 |     price
________________________________________________________________________________________

                 Cart       |    CartItem
                   id       |      id
                   user_id  |      cart_id
                            |      purchasable_id
                            |      purchasable_type
                            |      quantity

                 //purchasble: polymorphic, Combo and Product are purchasable
```

An example would be much more easier to understand

```
Product: Some Shirt, Some Pants, SomeOther Shirt, etc.,
Combo: Shirt + Pants combo (discount: $20)

For the product 'Some Shirt',
Variants: Small ($30), Medium ($35), Large ($40)
OptionTypes: Print, Add-ons
OptionValues for 'Print': CustomLogo ($10), FullSizePrint ($20)
OptionValues for 'Add-ons': Frills ($1), InnerPockets ($2)
```

When I add something to cart, a `Cart` gets created and new `CartItem` gets created for a new `Cart` just created. And my question is

> How do I get the variant and options user has selected?

***Note**: I don't wan't to send an array of `optionValueId`s and `variantId` in json and calculate and copy price to `CartItem`: I really need those `optionValueId`s and `variantId`s to persist i.e., in db.

Right now, `CartItem` contains only the `id` of the `Product` and obviously `Product.Variants` would give all possible variants, same for `OptionTypes` and `OptionValues`

I looked shallowly at how *Spree* does this: `CartItem` has `variant_id` instead of `product_id`. In other words, they add `Variants` to cart and get the product object `:via` variant. Well they eliminate the need for separately sending `variantId` but I still don't know how they get and where they store an array of `optionValueId`s user has selected. I also looked at this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240226/using-spree-how-can-i-find-product-option-values-from-an-order-in-rails-console) but it doesn't have any answer and moreover it was more specific to *Spree*.

**What I thought of?**

- Add another column `options_chosen` in `CartItem` and send in a serialized array of `optionValueId`s user has chosen; *Why it could be bad?* Firstly, it doesn't work for `Combo`. Secondly, *Atomicity* is lost.
- Add column `options_chosen` in a new Model called `CartVariant` referencing `Variant` and add `CartVariant`s *the Spree way* to cart. *My thoughts:* I don't know if this is **the** right way to do it. Getting product object should be like `CartItem.CartVariant.Variant.Product` and I don't know how to make this work for `Combo`s. Btw, even here atomicity is lost;

Comment: Hi Zeke, I am struggling with this exact issue right now. Did you figure it out? I have a product page with two variants available for a customer to choose from. I've thought of a few ways to do it, but they all feel like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

I included the product_id as a hidden field on the product's page, and then created radio input buttons to choose a specific variant. When I submitted the form, I'm passing the product_id and variant_id params to the LineItems controller, where I use them to build my line_item. Does that make sense? I've been working on this for hours, and it finally works!

```
<%= form_tag line_items_path, method: :post, :id => "print_form" do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, @product.id %>

  <% @product.variants.each do |variant| %>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="variant_id" value="<%= variant.id %>" /><%= variant.name %>
    </label>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: There's absolutely no problem finding which `variant` the user has added to `cart`, becoz I do not add `products`, but `variants` to cart _(I can identify the product using `variant.product`)_  as _Spree_ does. This way, i do not even need to send the `product_id`s to server.

Comment: The real problem lies in sending `OptionTypes` and `OptionValues`. What's more, they are nested under `Variant`s when it comes to `Combo`s, thereby preventing us from linking those directly to `CartItem` or `LineItem`

Comment: Right, but why aren't you also adding the OptionTypes and OptionValues, the same way I'm sending the Variant selections along with the Product? It just becomes multiple related LineItems in my cart.